# Remove camera distortion without chessboard, by object and contour points

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, javacv

I need correct the distortion of my camera without using a chessboard target. I have a snapshot of a rectangular object. To do this I first found some points of the rectangular object on my image. As a result, I have the coordinates of real object points and of points of object contour in image. This is depicted on the image here:
https://yadi.sk/i/PgPYJvAQs8YwQ
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1uajFxXL5MUMnFiVjVjbF8tTVE/view

How can I proceed on JavaCV or OpenCV?

Comment: Your google drive file is not shared.

Comment: Sorry, I fixed it.

Comment: In my childhood, my dad always win me at chess. Since then, I hate chess, chessboards and all that are associated with this. If serious, my camera always shot objects in rectangular region. During work procces camera position can change. To this did not affect the shooting, I mark workspace color rectangular. In work procces I keep getting its contours and do perspective correction by cernels coordinates. I think this data enough to correct lens barrel distortion. Therefore, use the chessboard seems to me superfluous.

Comment: @FedorM Did you find a way in the end..?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using findHomography function in opencv, that uses RANSAC to account for outliers and get an initial estimate of the image transformation.

```
Mat h = findHomography(distorted_src,undistort_dst);
warpPerspective(im_src, im_undistort, h, size);
```

Comment: If I correct understand you - this method let me correct perpictive transorm on my images. But I need correct lens barrel distortion on this image. (Perspective correction are already done, and sides of rectangular object are correct painted on result image and this object is centrally located)

Answer (score 0):

A few points:

1. Your choice of corresponding distorted/undistorted points in your example image is wrong. Since you are interested in barrel (a.k.a. radial) distortion only, matched points should be on the same radii.
2. If your correspondences are exact, meaning that you can identify the undistorted versions of each distorted point, and know their undistorted coordinates, then the problem is not different that using a "checkerboard" pattern: you just approach it as a standard non-linear least-squares problem
3. If the correspondences are inexact, the only constraint you can impose is that straight lines must be straight. The main reference for this approach is https://hal.inria.fr/inria-00267247/document